# Remove Expo SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, expo, react-native

I am trying to update my Google Play store app but I am getting a warning that my some devices wont update because I have System alert window permission I am working in expo managed workflow please help me to get rid of this permission I tried a lot but no success how I can remove this permission from my expo react native project

Thanks

Comment: Do you find any solution? I have same problem

Answer (score 0):

Expo managed workflow doesn’t allow access to the manifest file to remove permission so we have to build a plugin that modifies its content.
you have to add a config plugin to remove SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission from the Info.plist and AndroidManifest.xml.
First, create an android-manifest.plugin.js file in the folder of your project with the following code:

```
const { withAndroidManifest } = require("@expo/config-plugins");
module.exports = function androiManifestPlugin(config) {
  return withAndroidManifest(config, async (config) => {
    let androidManifest = config.modResults.manifest;
    androidManifest.$ = {
      ...androidManifest.$,
      "xmlns:tools": "http://schemas.android.com/tools",
    };
    androidManifest["uses-permission"] = androidManifest["uses-permission"].map(
      (perm) => {
        if (
          perm.$["android:name"] === "android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"
        ) {
          perm.$["tools:node"] = "remove";
        }
        return perm;
      }
    );
    return config;
  });
};
```

Then add the plugin to the app.json file as follow:

```
"expo":{
...
"plugins": ["./android-manifest.plugin.js"],
...
}
```

and build your app with eas build command.
For more details go to https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/