# Can not remove system_alert_window permission from react native project made by expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a React Native project created with command expo init and built with expo build:android and I tried to remove `system_alert_permission` with no luck.

things that I've tried:

1. adding below code to `AndroidManifest.xml` file in debug, main and release directory:
   [image]
2. adding below code to `app.json`:
   "permissions": []

both of which didn't remove the permission. any idea how to do this?

thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi. I have same problem. did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Expo managed workflow doesn’t allow access to the manifest file to remove permission so we have to build a plugin that modifies its content.
You can find the answer in the following link:

[how to build the plugin to modify Info.plist and AndroidManifest.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66657605/remove-expo-system-alert-window-permission-android/72532245#72532245)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove any permission from the final `AndroidManifest.xml` file by using the `android.blockedPermissions` property in your app config file (`app.config.js` / `app.config.json`).

Read the docs:
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#blockedpermissions